# React-Navigation: Call function whenever page is navigated to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a React-Native app using React-Navigation, and I am using a stack navigator.

How can I call a function whenever a page is navigated to, including on goBack() events? If I place the method in my constructor, it is only triggered on its initial creation, and not when it is attained through goBack().

Answer (score 4):

use Navigation Events
I believe you can use did focus and will blur

```
<NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus', payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus', payload)}
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur', payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur', payload)}
    />
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

***EDIT 2022***

`import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';`

`const isFocused = useIsFocused();`

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
 if(isFocused){

   // callback
 }
},[isFocused])
```

Comment: This works well with the v3 of the package.

Comment: This works well with the v3 of the package.

Comment: works on 2022 too...thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you noted the component is never unmounted when changing pages, so you can't rely on the constructor or even `componentDidMount`. There is a lot of discussion about this topic [in this issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/51).

You could e.g. listen to the `didFocus` and `willBlur` events and only render your page when it is focused.

**Example**

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFocused: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = [
      this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: true })
      }),
      this.props.navigation.addListener("willBlur", () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: false })
      })
    ];
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.remove());
  }

  render() {
    const { isFocused } = this.state;

    if (!isFocused) {
      return null;
    }

    return <MyComponent />;
  }
}
```